# Use Twilio and Zapier to change a Wordpress Post Status

Tags: wordpress, post, sms, twilio, zapier

I am using Twilio to get an SMS notification for when a new post is created on my WordPress site. It is working great, however I am wondering if it is possible to reply to the text to change the post status to published?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not with Zapier directly, but [Twilio can capture your reply](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/replying-to-sms-messages) and using the [WP REST API](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/posts/#schema-status) you can make an API call to WordPress to update the post status. You might even be able to use [Code by Zapier](https://zapier.com/zapbook/code/) to make the API call from JavaScript.